# How do you open remote directory using iText PDF Java library?

Tags: java, itext

I am using the iText PDF library in my Java app to generate test scenario reports. In the report, I'm populating a table with a row for each scenario. I'm trying to make the first cell of each row link to the scenario's respective directory:

`PdfPCell scenarioCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase( new Chunk( ri.getScenarioFile() + " (" + ri.getId() + ")", this.defaultFont ).setRemoteGoto( "instances/" + ri.getId(), "Instance Directory" ) ) );`

The above code works to link to the correct location, however, it seems to force my computer to open the file into my default text editor (thus resulting in a message along the lines of "Cannot Open. File 'instances/Scenario_1234' is a directory.")

Is there any way to force this link to open the directory using the machine's default file browser without losing cross-platform adherence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText PDF: (taken from comment)

```
PdfAction.createLaunch( "instances" + File.separator + ri.getId(), null, null, null );
```

JAVA:

Try to use Desktop
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
d.open(new File("dirpath"));
```

Comment: That would be the way to open the directory into the native file browser from a Java app, and not from a PDF document generated by my Java app, as I asked.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question.Probably idea is to add slash on the end of path or to use `setAction(new PdfAction(dirpath))`. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: No worries, yeah I just started trying to use PdfAction, passing the directory as a URL, but now I'm having troubles with the URL resolving the absolute path as if it were a relative path.

So if I make a URL pointing to "file:///home/user/scenarios/instances/instance1234" it resolves as "file:///home/user/scenarios/file:///home/user/scenarios/instances/instance1234" essentially resolving to the current working directory of the PDF for some reason..

Comment: Ok now I think I have it working with:
`PdfAction.createLaunch( "instances" + File.separator + ri.getId(), null, null, null )`
Thanks for your help!